# GeoJson Vector Tiles with TM2 and tilelive-vector

Tags: mapbox, tilemill

I want to serve GeoJson tiles from a MBTiles vector datastore using the mapbox tools.
Is this possible?

What i've done so far:

- cloned and installed a lot of repositories: TM2, tilelive, tilelive-vector, mbtiles, ...
- imported a shapefile into TM2
- applied a style (is this even necessary for serving GeoJson?)
- exported the style and a MBTiles database

To check, if the MBTiles file can be read, I've tried this.

```
var tilelive = require('tilelive');
var MBTiles = require('mbtiles');
MBTiles.registerProtocols(tilelive);
var listsrc = function(src){ console.log('src: ' + src); }
tilelive.list('/home/bergw/Downloads', listsrc);
```

But it returns: `null`

Even more questions coming up, when trying to use `tilelive-vector`:

```
var opts = {};
opts.xml = 'file:///home/bergw/getgeojson/project.xml';
//opts.xml = 'file:///home/bergw/shapefiles/source.tm2/data.xml';
opts.format = 'json';
//opts.base = !style.tmpid(id) && uri.pathname;
opts.scale = 1; // data.scale || 1;
opts.source = 'mbtiles:///home/bergw/Downloads/source.mbtiles';
//opts.source = new MBTiles('/home/bergw/Downloads/source.mbtiles')
//opts.source = 'tmsource:///home/bergw/shapefiles/source.tm2';
v = new Vector(opts, done);
```

`project.xml` is the mapnik style, I've extracted from the exported `tm2z`.
It still contains the reference to the original shapefile, but if I don't use it, I get `Error: No xml`.

With all the combinations I've tried for the source parameter, I get `Error: Invalid tilesource protocol`.

Any help on how to proceed or a hint which other tools, or combination thereof, would be more appropriate, is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Wilhelm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TileMill 2 is designed to create [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) as vector tiles rather than GeoJSON. It's also not a server, but a design & creation tool, so would be ill-fitted to your present usecase. Something like [this tutorial for TileStache](http://mattmakesmaps.com/blog/2013/10/09/tilestache-rendering-topojson/) would be a better option for you.

Comment: Sorry, I commited the previous comment unintentionally: Thank you for the link, but in the meantime I got a prototype working by using mapnik and a custom Leaflet GridLayer.
Performance is fantastic! Even with several 10,000 of polygons.
Once again, thank you for providing such great tools and developing them in the open.

Comment: @WilhelmBerg any chance you cold post a link to your code, I would be very interested in this. Thanks>

Comment: I never finished that project. If you are interested in vector rendering you might take a look at MapBox GL: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl/ https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js